# OpenVidu - Adding stream for existing publisher - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using openvidu for one of my projects. Say there are 2 users User-A and User-B. Both are publishers and wish to subscribe to each others videos. User-A initiated conference session. Once User-B join streamCreated is triggered for User-B in javascript on User-A browser. But User-B is unaware that User-A exists. For this we pull exisiting publishers for get-session api call, but that does not give access to stream. How to get access to stream, all we have is stream id

Answer (score 0):

User B will always receive (just after successfully calling `Session.connect()` method) one `connectionCreated` event for each user already connected to the session and one `streamCreated` event for each stream already being published into the session.